# Internet Download Manager(IDM) in Metro UI Internet Explorer

Tags: windows-8, download-manager

How to use  the Internet Download Manager(IDM) inside the Metro UI Internet Explorer. I Used it in Desktop Version but eager to use it in Metro Version?

Comment: It is very likely you will never be able to since its a add-on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not getting you wrong then you are talking about the IDM(Internet download manger) for the windows(correct me if I'm going in wrong direction). If you want to use IDM for the IE for ModernUI then I don't think they have updated it yet.  So I think you have to wait until they don't fix it.

> Version 6.12 adds IDM download panel for web-players that can be used
>   to download flash videos from sites like YouTube, MySpaceTV, and
>   Google Videos. It also features complete Windows 7 and Vista support,
>   YouTube grabber, redeveloped scheduler, and MMS protocol support. The
>   new version also adds improved integration for IE and IE based
>   browsers, redesigned and enhanced download engine, the unique advanced
>   integration into all latest browsers, improved toolbar, and a wealth
>   of other improvements and new features.

[IDM](http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/)

Comment: Yes you are correct.

Comment: So yet there is no update for the ModernUI they have, you have to live with it.

Answer (score 1):

So far you cannot access the Downloads in the ModernUI Internet Explorer. There are some workarounds available:

- After the download you get directly a "Open" button for the recently downloaded file
- Otherwise you need to go to the Desktop Internet Explorer

[image]

and then view the downloads (Ctrl+J) as in old days.

[image]

Comment: Considering you cannot use add-ons with the Modern UI Internet Explorer I am not sure where the second image came from.

Comment: As I said in my answer - when you open the Desktop IE with `View on the Desktop` you'll have all these options...

Answer (score 0):

I use IE 11 with the latest IDM build , I noticed that it now works with the metro app! It also shows the download video bar , but this functionality is only limited to videos(flash).